# How can I permanently add an Item to a comboBox in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, combobox, save

I have a comboBox and I can save an item to it in runtime, but, every time I close the application the items disappear, I have searched for it, but, i couldn't find anything to do so.

I have the following code:

```
if (!comboBox1.Items.Contains(comboBox1.Text))
    comboBox1.Items.Add(comboBox1.Text);
```

It's a Windows form application, it uses C# and SQL for managing a DB and it's tables, I would like to use o comboBox so the user don't need to type the same thing over and over when is going to put a value.

Is there a way to "permanently" save the items? Maybe using an SQL DB ou something like that?

Comment: What type of application is this? (web, console, windows, ... ?)

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's a Windows form application, it uses C# and SQL for managing a DB and it's tables, I would like to use o comboBox so the user don't need to type the same thing over and over when is going to put a value.

Comment: So you want to persist user input and reload it upon the next start. Decide where to store it and if it will be for the application or for each user. Then store and reload. It is not really possible to store runtime data inside the application. Common storage can be registry, text files, often in an application roaming folder  or the database itself. Pick yours!

Comment: Another option is the Application Settings feature: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/application-settings-overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either define the ComboBox items in a database table or in your application. If you're looking for a quick solution and know what all of the ComboBox options should be, you can define them in an array and then assign that array to the ComboBox DataSource:

```
string[] items = new string[] {"--Select--", "Item1", "Item2"};
comboBox1.DataSource = items;
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: I used a fileStream to create and append a file, so I can store the name of the Items

Comment: _If you're looking for a quick solution and know what all of the ComboBox options should be,_ No, OP explicitly wrote he wants to persist user input. A file or the DBMS are good solutions..